# Verified good `mkisofs` for CentOS 8?

Tags: centos, iso, bootable

I'm running through the steps to add a kickstart to a CentOS 8 ISO. I've looked at Red Hat's documentation for RHEL5 through RHEL8, and several probably outdated web pages.

- I know the `dd` command to burn the new ISO works with an unmodified ISO. The USB drive is bootable in that case.
- I know I have a good kickstart file.
- I've made the modifications to `isolinux/isolinux.cfg` to add `ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg`.
- I even found the documentation about adding `inst.ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg` to `EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg`.

And in every case, `mkisofs` still won't make a bootable USB drive. The USB drive is *readable*, once the regular OS is running and it's bootable if I `dd` the existing ISO onto it. I think I've ruled out everything except for something missing in this command. (The `-V` volume name is taken directly from running the `blkid` command on the downloaded base ISO.)

```
mkisofs \
  -o ../CentOS-8.3.2011-x86_64-ks.iso \
  -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
  -J -R -l -v \
  -c isolinux/boot.cat \
  -no-emul-boot \
  -boot-load-size 4 \
  -boot-info-table \
  -eltorito-alt-boot \
  -graft-points \
  -V "CentOS-8-3-2011-x86_64-dvd" .
```

Once I have this part figured out, I'll document the whole process. Everything I've found out there right now is at least two years old.

Comment: Your question contains a contradiction: "mkisofs still won't make a bootable USB drive" and "it's bootable if I dd the existing ISO onto it". Is it bootable or not?

Comment: @berndbausch - If I take the default ISO from CentOS and burn it onto the USB drive, the drive is bootable. If I then modify that ISO through the documented processes to add a kickstart file, run mkisofs, and burn the result onto the USB drive, the drive is readable but not bootable.

Comment: To be honest, the `mkisofs` options are black magic to me, but the descriptions for RHEL 7 and 8 include a last step, `isohybrid --uefi /tmp/yourname.iso`. If you have a Red Hat subscription, these instructions are a few weeks old: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/60959.

Comment: @berndbausch - I'll give you credit for the "black magic" thought. After I gave up trying to tidy the `mkisofs` command, things like putting the arguments in alphabetical order, etc., the USB drive became bootable. I'm on to additional problems, but I have a solution for this one. Posting shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was basically to quit trying to out-think the documentation. **Don't edit the `mkisofs` command!** Run it the way it's given in the documentation. The only modification I've made is to add the `-v` for verbose output. [This was the page](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/optimized-iso-image) that I wound up working from.

```bsh
d_build_dir=/tmp/iso
df_dest_iso=/path/to/CentOS-8.3-2011-x86_64-ks.iso
d_usb_device=/dev/sdb

cd ${d_build_dir}
time mkisofs \
  -o ${df_dest_iso} \
  -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
  -J -R -l -v \
  -c isolinux/boot.cat \
  -no-emul-boot \
  -boot-load-size 4 \
  -boot-info-table \
  -eltorito-alt-boot \
  -e images/efiboot.img \
  -no-emul-boot \
  -graft-points \
  -V "CentOS-8-3-2011-x86_64-dvd" \
  -jcharset utf-8 .

isohybrid --uefi ${df_dest_iso}
implantisomd5 ${df_dest_iso}

umount ${d_usb_device}1
time dd if=${df_dest_iso} of=${d_usb_device} status=progress
```

One thing that page got wrong was that you need to do the `implantisomd5` **last**. Otherwise, the `isohybrid` command will make changes to the ISO that will break the md5 verification hashes.

These steps get me a bootable ISO on a USB flash drive. It does not yet give me a **usable** installer. I'm still working my through getting usable `isolinux.cfg` or `grub.cfg` modifications. I'm keeping my notes at my [github project](https://github.com/dafydd2277/systemAdmin/tree/master/kickstart/centos8).