# CentOS 8 Custom ISO - Adding `ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg` Hangs the Installer

Tags: centos, iso, kickstart

In trying to build a custom kickstart ISO for CentOS 8, I'm tripping on getting
the installer to run. [The ISO is bootable now](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640232/verified-good-mkisofs-for-centos-8/640786#640786), but the boot process
hangs at where I think the installer should be starting.

In adding the customized kickstart file, I need to edit two files to
reference that kickstart file at boot time.

- For BIOS installations, [this page](https://www.golinuxhub.com/2017/05/how-to-create-customized-bootable-boot/) tells me to edit `isolinux/isolinux.cfg` to add `ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg` to the ends of the lines starting with `append`.
- For UEFI installations, [this page](https://www.thegeeksearch.com/installing-uefi-linux-with-kickstart/) suggested editing `EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg` to add `inst.ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg` to the ends of the lines starting with `linuxefi`.

Either or both of those modifcations caused the installer boot process to hang.
However, if I added a `/ks.cfg` to the root of the ISO and executed `mkisofs`
*without* modifying those files, I could get a default installer. So,
*something* about adding `[inst.]ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg` to those two files is
causing the ISO installer to hang, and the plain existance of the kickstart
file is not a factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old ways of doing things don't work in CentOS 8. The range of options for
looking up and executing from a kickstart file have expanded. This has forced
the `inst.ks` option to be more detailed than before. The first clue came from
Red Hat's [Advanced Boot Options](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_installation/kickstart-and-advanced-boot-options_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user#kickstart-boot-options_kickstart-and-advanced-boot-options) documentation. It says,

> If you specify a device and not a path, the installation program looks for the
> Kickstart file in /ks.cfg on the device that you specify.

But, `[inst.]ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg` doesn't actually specify a device! If you look
at those `append` or `linuxefi` lines, you'll see an entry for the stage2
installer:

`inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=CentOS-8-3-2011-x86_64-dvd`

Note that it specifies a device TYPE of `hd`. The specific `hd` device for the
stage2 installer is identified by `LABEL=CentOS-8-3-2011-x86_64-dvd`. So, given
the Red Hat blockquote above, the CORRECT way to specify the kickstart file
named `ks.cfg` in the root of the ISO is

`inst.ks=hd:LABEL=CentOS-8-3-2011-x86_64-dvd`

If you want to use a different name for your kickstart file, you can add

`inst.ks=hd:LABEL=CentOS-8-3-2011-x86_64-dvd:/<filename>`

using whatever filename suits your use case. For more information on the format
of the ISO boot options, [check this out](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_installation/kickstart-and-advanced-boot-options_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user#installation-source-boot-options_kickstart-and-advanced-boot-options).